# How to separate values in a column into different fields?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

For example, I have a list with two columns(person_name, values). 
The values are (a, qq;ww;ee;rr). I have to separate the values with the semicolon. Such that I will get a list with 4 fields as follows:

person_name | values 
a           | qq
a           | ww
a           | ee
a           | rrr

I don't have the SharePoint 2013 workflow available. Is there a way to do this? Maybe by using a calculated column? I am new to SharePoint. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by creating **calculated columns**. For testing purposes just create a new list with just a title column. Add a single item with your value qq;ww;ee;rr as title.

Now you add calculated columns for your splitted values. The first one is pretty easy. Name it something like "Col1" and set it to calcuated column "Single line of text". Here is your formula:

```
=LEFT(Title;INT(FIND(";";Title)-1))
```

For the second part of your title value add another calculated column "Col2" again as "Single line of text". The formula goes here:

```
=LEFT(MID(Title;FIND(";";Title)+1;FIND(";";Title;FIND(";";Title)+1));INT(FIND(";";MID(Title;FIND(";";Title)+1;FIND(";";Title;FIND(";";Title)+1)))-1))
```

**Now your list has three columns:**

Title

Col1

Col2

**The values are:**

qq;ww;ee;rr

qq

ww

[image: Screenshot of the results]

Now you got the way to create formulas for further columns. 
For further information to the used functions see this Microsoft support articles:

[FIND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-function-06213f91-b5be-4544-8b0b-2fd5a775436f)

[MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-function-2eba57be-0c05-4bdc-bf81-5ecf4421eb8a)

[LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-function-913824B4-FC42-4C8C-9229-0EAA57DCDF49)

**Please give this answer a positive feedback if this helps. Thank you.**

*Further comment: You have changed your post lately. Your new requirement - not splitting into columns but splitting into new items - is not possible using calculated columns. You will have to use a workflow engine like SharePoint Workflow or Nintex Workflow or will have to solve this by developing a solution.*

Comment: I am very new to SharePoint and I have no idea how to go about developing a solution. If possible, could you direct me to some pages that would give me a guidline to develop a solution? I don't have SharePoint 2013 workflow which prevents me from using the split string workflow. I will look into using Nintex workflows though. Thank you.

Comment: @shasha0607 The easiest way to resolve your requirement ist by workflow (Nintex or SharePoint). It would cost you only 30 minutes to resolve this. I am not a SharePoint developer - more a system administrator and workflow designer. So I am sorry I cannot give you any help for solving this by development. I am sure you will have a hard time trying to develop a solution for SharePoint when being new to SharePoint. My attempt would be getting a workflow engine running. That can make your SharePoint life much easier in the future as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that. I only have SharePoint 2010 workflows available, so I will have to do some custom coding(which I don't know how to do in SharePoint).

Comment: For asking your next SharePoint question please add a tag "2010". As you have set the tags "SharePoint-Enterprise" and "SharePoint-Online" all of us think you have SharePoint Online or SharePoint 2016 in use. Using the right tags makes solution finding easier for us. I am sorry, I do not know about developing for SharePoint 2010. Maybe ask a new question, use 2010 tag and describe your requirements extensive. For best answers add a "development" in the questions title. Then just devs will open up your question and you will not get any other answers. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider column name is "A2" & it's value is: `49258- Alpha`

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(",",A2,1))
```

Output = Alpha

&

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(",", A2)-1)
```

Output = 49258

Comment: Hi, can you add at least some explanation to the answer please?